# Sketching this subset in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{C}, b \neq 0$ and define
$$G_0 := \left\{z \in \mathbb{C}\left| Im\left(\frac{z-a}{b}\right)=0\right.\right\}.$$

I need to sketch $G_0$. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\frac{z-a}{b-0}=\frac{AM}{OB}$ can you continue from here?

Comment: What do you mean with $\frac{AM}{OB}$?

Comment: I mean to take $z_M=z$, $z_A=a$, $z_B=b$, $z_O=0$

Comment: Let $z=x+iy$, $a=\alpha+\beta i$ and $b=\gamma+\phi i$, then simplify the equation. You'll find a line! $$y=\frac{\phi}{\gamma}x+\beta-\alpha\frac{\phi}{\gamma}$$

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $$\boxed{\Im(w)= 0 \iff w\in \mathbb{R} \iff w = \overline{w}}$$ So $$ \frac{z-a}{b} = \frac{\overline{z}-\overline{a}}{\overline{b}}$$ so

$$ (z-a)\overline{b} = (\overline{z}-\overline{a})b$$ so $$ z\overline{b}-a\overline{b} = \overline{z}a-\overline{a}b$$ so this is some line....

Answer (score 0):

Take $z_M=z$, $z_A=a$, $z_B=b$, $z_O=0$.
So we have, $Im(\frac{z-a}{b-0})=Im(\frac{AM}{OB})=0$
Thus, $\frac{AM}{OB}$ is a real number, and so $arg(AM)=arg(OB)$ **or** $arg(AM)=\pi + arg(OB)$

Which gives that $(AM)$ is parellal to $(OB)$